# Junit 5 performing tests in maven build even when not annotated

Tags: java, maven, junit5

While preparing a **release on maven** (*release:prepare*) I've commented some tests I don't want to perform, but they are executed anyway, even completely removing the `@Test` annotation form the method.

NOTE: Consider that the Skip Test option is ignored during maven release

The build was performed under Eclipse wit the **following environment**:

- Apache Maven 3.5.4 external run-time (not the one embedded in Eclipse)

- Java JDK 1.8.0_151

- maven-compiler-plugin 3.0

- maven-release-plugin 2.5.3

- junit-jupiter-api 5.5.2

- junit-jupiter-engine 5.5.2

Usually to skip a test I comment only the annotation:

```
    //@Test
    public void testIwantToSkip() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
```

At the moment the only way I've found to skip a test is to comment the whole method, but I expect it to be skipped only commenting the annotation, like it happened on Junit 4.

**UPDATE**

I've also tried to use the  `@Disable` annotation, unfortunately with no result. Sample:

```
@Test
@Disabled
public void testAuditMapper() {
    ....
}
```

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

After several tests and thanks to Kayaman hint I've figured out that under Maven build the annotations are totally ignored, only methods that start  with "`test`" will be executed, the others will be totally ignored, regardless of the annotations. In example:

```
@Test
public void someThing() {
    // will NOT be executed....
}

@Disabled
public void testSomeThing() {
    // will be executed....
}
```

**DEFINITIVE SOLUTION**

In the build section of my pom the surefire plugin was not specified, so the resulting pom was using the 2.12.4 version of this plugin. By adding this in the build section:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
</plugin>
```

everything works as expected. Thanks @asa for hint.

Comment: Have you recompiled the project after commenting out the tests?

Comment: Of course, I've also tried to perform clean+install goals, without the skip test option, and the commented tests are executed anyway. I think Junit5 performs introspection of public methods and consider it as tests without regarding of the annotation.

Comment: If you rename the method to `iWantToSkip()` does it still get run? Back in the day test methods were identified by the `test` in the beginning of a method, so that's probably a backwards compatibility issue. Maybe it can be disabled in configuration.

Comment: Are they *built* or *run*?

Comment: @Raedwald I think I got your question now: if I run the test directly as Junit it works normally, both commenting the test annotation and using the disable annotations. It "fails" only under Maven build

Comment: @Kayaman after several tests I can confirm that you figured out the right cause: the test is done in ANY case if the method starts with "test", by opposite is TOTALLY IGNORED if is named in another way, regardless of any kind od annotation; the annotations work correctly under Junit Run, while under Maven build the name of method rules

Comment: Does your test class extend TestCase? If so then you’re accidentally using JUnit 3. JUnit 4 and 5 no longer require that mechanism.

Comment: No @johanneslink, is not my case. But for sure is connected with some backward compatibility (that I repeat is nearly a nonsense for me)

Comment: If tests only run if they are named `test*` than you are not using JUnit Jupiter ...than you have some JUnit4/3 dependencies in your tree which produces the issue...and of course it's needed to have the correct dependency to junit jupiter engine ...see the docs of surefire...

Comment: Yes of course @khmarbaise, the problem was directly connected with the version of surefire plugin I was using, it was suggested by the user asa some answers below, I updated my post and solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are experiencing the issue during the release:perform goal, you will not be able to change your java class.
Normally the perform goal takes the class committed in your SCM during the release:prepare phase.
Your only options at this stage would be disable all the tests during the perform stage or rollback the commits from the prepare goal and use the conditional test features of Junit5 to condition their executions.

UPDATED Solution:

The maven project was using the default version of the surefire plugins (used for units tests) and not a more recent one which resolves some issues with JUnit 5.

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
</plugin>
```

Note: the use of the following plugin is very handly to ensure a project use the latest version of dependencies but most importantly the latest build ones:

https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/

Comment: Thanks asa, I was performing my tests during release:prepare with DryRun option, committing every time on SVN.

Comment: this is strange then since I do not have issues myself with tests marked as disabled. the only difference that i can see from your description is the version of maven I am using (3.6.2) but that shouldn't be relevant. The only relevant part is the surefire plugin (i think I recall some issues with old versions of that plugins and junit5) i'm using the version 3.0.0-M3 on my projects

Comment: I would say **SOLVED** @asa. I've never specified the surefire plugin under my maven poms, so the resulting version of surefire plugin was 2.12.4 (I think the embedded one). Now I've tried adding to pom the 3.0.0-M3 version and it works exactly as I expect: all the annotations are correctly interpreted, if I leave the test annotation from a method, even named "testSomeThing", it's NOT executed. I invite you to edit your message as the solution, so I can vote.

Comment: Done. i've also added a link to a very valuable plugin I use on my projects to make sure every thing stays up to date.  Anyhow, I'm glad you are sorted. have fun !

Answer (score 1):

Try using @Ignore annotation.

```
@Test
@Ignore("optional comment explaning the reason")
public void testIwantToSkip() {
    assertTrue(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint. Actually the (at)Ignore annotation is not available in Junit5, while there is another that should work the same way: (at)Disabled. Just tested but with no result, the test is performed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your note:

For the release plugin, you need to specify all options for the inner build indirectly, by wrapping them into

```
-Darguments="..."
```

Comment: Thanks it works and helps me a lot. It's not the best practice because ALL tests are skipped; I would have preferred the Disabled annotation to work properly but your hint is a faster work-around (faster than completely comment some tests).